# Angular custom autocomplete on key press

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a custom autocomplete on an input in angular 8.

So I have an input and I'm catching the tab key as below:

```
<input (keydown.Tab)="onKey($event)" />
```

then I have a method in the .ts file:

```
onKey(event) {
    // catch what's been typed in the input and autocomplete
}

words = {
    myword {
        result: 'myword param1 param2 param3'
    }
}
```

For example, if I type: `'myword'` in the input and press the Tab key it checks the word and then does the completion.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onKey(event) {
  if(this.words[event.target.value] != undefined) {
     event.target.value = this.words[event.target.value].result;
  }
}
words = {
  myword: {
    result: 'myword param1 param2 param3'
  }
}
```